# "Cannot GET /" when trying to connect to local express server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

After completing Code School's node.js course I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/dbainbridge/2424055) guide on how to set up a socket.io server with express 3, but when I try connecting to localhost:8080, it gives me "Cannot GET /".
My firewall is set to allow incoming and outgoing requests on port 8080, and I have the latest versions of express and socket.io installed.  My code is as follows:

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
var server = app.listen(8080);
var io = socket.listen(server);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var server = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Directory structure

```
C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\test\node_modules
                            \public\index.html
                            \app.js
```

EDIT:

This also does not work in app.js:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080);
var io = socket.listen(server);
```

Comment: Hm, since this is Windows, try changing the "/public" in `app.js` to "\public"?

Comment: When do you get the error? Like when you run app.js or when you Hit your server from browser? I'm not seeing any routes in your code. Also, Express 3 requires that you instantiate a `http.Server` to attach socket.io

Comment: @MOmary The Express static middleware will automatically serve up index.html from the specified static folder (in this case "public") if no / route is created. The above code works fine on Linux, which is why I'm thinking it's a Windows path problem.

Comment: @MOmary The error is displayed when trying to connect to localhost:8080.

Comment: @ScottGress I get the same error if I try \public

Comment: Hm, try `console.log(__dirname)` and check that the value is what you expect. What version of node are you running the script with?

Comment: @JosephWebber This code gives me error when I run it on 8080. As soon as I change the port, It works perfect. Try changing your port

Comment: @MOmary I get the same error no matter what port I use.

Comment: Did 'app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));' work for you? If not then try putting your code in a different drive, or run Node as administrator

Comment: @MOmary No, path did not work for me. I've got the latest version of Node installed, I get the same error from any directory, and I am the administrator on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I was getting the error because node is not smart enough to target index.htm by default from localhost:8080, and as such I needed to type localhost:8080/index.htm to access the page.

Comment: It was working great on my PC! anyhow, if you create a route like 'aap.get('/', function(req,res){res.sendFile('index.html');})' then localhost:8080 will directly take you to localhost:8080/index.html

Comment: @MOmary However, doing this gives the error `TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'sendFile'`, and according to another post it should be `res.send(status code, data);`.

Comment: Sorry, Actually I made a mistake, It's 'res.sendfile()' not sendFile

Comment: @MOmary Not to mention app instead of aap, and the semicolon at the end of the app.get method. It would look like this: `app.get('/', function(req,res){res.sendfile('index.html');});`

Answer (score 0):

Well If this is not working on windows then try doing this in your app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");
var path = require('path');
 // path is a built-in modules

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
var server = app.listen(8080);
var io = socket.listen(server);
```